# How can convert a datetime to double?

Tags: c#

How can convert a datetime to double?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need/want to do this? If it's for datetime arithmetic you should just use the static API of the DateTime class.

Comment: What format are you going for with this?  Seems a bit odd.  How do you want to represent the date in your floating point number?  EDIT: Ninja'd

Comment: What exactly would the double represent?

Comment: Like any other sort of date accumulator, a double as a date represents the number of units (nanoseconds, milliseconds, etc..) since some epoch.

Comment: @Ritch - what epoch and what units is exactly what @Mehrdad's asking.  Without knowing that it's hard to give an answer.  I'll note that your answer doesn't really fit this definition since the integral portion and fractional portion have different units in an OADate.

Comment: @tvanfosson I disagree. The OP wanted a double. I gave him a formatted double. I think there's some concern with the original intent of the function (ie: to support OLE Automation), but if the consumer of the double uses the documented values, then there's no problem in re-using that function. Now, I do doubt that the OP _actually_ needs a double, and could use the object directly as is.

Comment: @Ritch - I just meant that an OADate doesn't represent *the number of units...since some epoch*.  Strictly speaking the integral portion represents the number of days since the epoch while the fractional portion represents the percentage of hours in the day since midnight.  In some ways it can be handier for a particular purpose (the math is simpler to find the time of day, for example), but you can't, for instance, convert to different units easily since it doesn't represent a single unit measure.

Comment: @tvanfosson Oh, that clarifies things. I understand the issue you are raising.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var converted = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
```

Comment: Good answer to the question "How do I convert a DateTime into a date usable for OLE Automation?"  Since we don't know if that's what's needed for the OP, it's hard to up vote for this question.

Comment: @RitchMelton Good Answer I had not known the `ToOADate()` option in DateTime before

Comment: Its a double. If he uses the same epoch and counter amount, then it does what he needs. That information is in the help docs, linky: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx

Comment: I do concur with the why do you need this/what does it represent questions though.

Comment: @tvanfosson what does `OP` means

Comment: @Harsh - OP == Original Poster, in this case the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach than `ToOADate` is to use this:

```
double timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880654/1057791) where precision is lost when doing `DateTime.Now.AddTicks(1000).ToOADate()`, if the example there were changed to `(double)DateTime.Now.AddTicks(1000).Ticks` the precision is not lost.